# Как задать элементу массив из чисел?

Tags: javascript

Пытаюсь разработать схему присвоения одному элементу нескольких значений в виде массива из чисел. В чем суть, у меня есть 10 input с типом checkbox. Мне нужно каждому из них присвоить массив из годов (к примеру, инпуту c label 1930-ые присвоить массив из 1930, 1931 и тд). И когда будут выбраны, допустим, 1930-ые и 1940-ые, нужно, чтобы в консоль выводился массив из годов, присвоенных выбранным инпутам. Предоставляю код для удобства.

```js
const decadesList = document.getElementById('decadesList');
const decadesCols = document.querySelectorAll('.decades-col');
const decadesInput = document.querySelectorAll('.decades-input');

let decadesInput1 = document.getElementById('decadesInput1');
let decadesInput2 = document.getElementById('decadesInput2');
let decadesInput3 = document.getElementById('decadesInput3');
let decadesInput4 = document.getElementById('decadesInput4');
let decadesInput5 = document.getElementById('decadesInput5');
let decadesInput6 = document.getElementById('decadesInput6');
let decadesInput7 = document.getElementById('decadesInput7');
let decadesInput8 = document.getElementById('decadesInput8');
let decadesInput9 = document.getElementById('decadesInput9');
let decadesInput10 = document.getElementById('decadesInput10');

decadesInput1 = [1930, 1931, 1932, 1933, 1934, 1935, 1936, 1937, 1938, 1939];
decadesInput2 = [1940, 1941, 1942, 1943, 1944, 1945, 1946, 1947, 1948, 1949];
decadesInput3 = [1950, 1951, 1952, 1953, 1954, 1955, 1956, 1957, 1958, 1959];
decadesInput4 = [1960, 1961, 1962, 1963, 1964, 1965, 1966, 1967, 1968, 1969];
decadesInput5 = [1970, 1971, 1972, 1973, 1974, 1975, 1976, 1977, 1978, 1979];
decadesInput6 = [1980, 1981, 1982, 1983, 1984, 1985, 1986, 1987, 1988, 1989];
decadesInput7 = [1990, 1991, 1992, 1993, 1994, 1995, 1996, 1997, 1998, 1999];
decadesInput8 = [2000, 2001, 2002, 2003, 2004, 2005, 2006, 2007, 2008, 2009];
decadesInput9 = [2010, 2011, 2012, 2013, 2014, 2015, 2016, 2017, 2018, 2019];
decadesInput10 = [2020, 2021, 2022];

decadesList.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
  for (let i = 0; i < decadesInput.length; i++) {
    if (decadesInput[i].checked) {
      console.log(decadesInput[i].checked);
      break;
    } else {
      console.log('No time was chosen')
    }
  }
});
```

```css
.decades-list {
  position: absolute;
  top: 35%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  transition: all 2s;
  margin-top: 50px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-around;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  list-style: none;
}

.decades-col {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  margin: 0 40px;
  list-style: none;
}

.decades-item {
  margin: 15px 0;
  display: flex;
  position: relative;
}

.decades-input {
  position: absolute;
  width: 1px;
  height: 1px;
  margin: -1px;
  padding: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  border: 0;
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  appearance: none;
}

.decades-input:checked+.decades-span {
  border-color: #21ebff;
  box-shadow: 0 0 0 15px #21ebff inset;
}

.decades-label {
  padding-left: 40px;
  word-spacing: 3px;
  font-family: 'Marvel';
  font-size: 26px;
  color: #202020;
  -webkit-user-select: none;
  user-select: none;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.decades-span {
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  border-radius: 100px;
  background-color: #FFF;
  border: 3px solid #21ebff;
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 0px 0px #21ebff inset;
  cursor: pointer;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: -1;
}

.decades-span::after {
  content: '';
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  opacity: 0;
  z-index: 4;
  position: absolute;
}
```

```html
<div class="decades-list" id="decadesList">
  <ul class="decades-col">
    <li class="decades-item">
      <input type="checkbox" class="decades-input" id="decadesInput1">
      <span class="decades-span"></span>
      <label for="decadesInput1" class="decades-label">The 1930s</label>
    </li>
    <li class="decades-item">
      <input type="checkbox" class="decades-input" id="decadesInput2">
      <span class="decades-span"></span>
      <label for="decadesInput2" class="decades-label">The 1940s</label>
    </li>
    <li class="decades-item">
      <input type="checkbox" class="decades-input" id="decadesInput3">
      <span class="decades-span"></span>
      <label for="decadesInput3" class="decades-label">The 1950s</label>
    </li>
    <li class="decades-item">
      <input type="checkbox" class="decades-input" id="decadesInput4">
      <span class="decades-span"></span>
      <label for="decadesInput4" class="decades-label">The 1960s</label>
    </li>
    <li class="decades-item">
      <input type="checkbox" class="decades-input" id="decadesInput5">
      <span class="decades-span"></span>
      <label for="decadesInput5" class="decades-label">The 1970s</label>
    </li>
  </ul>
  <ul class="decades-col">
    <li class="decades-item">
      <input type="checkbox" class="decades-input" id="decadesInput6">
      <span class="decades-span"></span>
      <label for="decadesInput6" class="decades-label">The 1980s</label>
    </li>
    <li class="decades-item">
      <input type="checkbox" class="decades-input" id="decadesInput7">
      <span class="decades-span"></span>
      <label for="decadesInput7" class="decades-label">The 1990s</label>
    </li>
    <li class="decades-item">
      <input type="checkbox" class="decades-input" id="decadesInput8">
      <span class="decades-span"></span>
      <label for="decadesInput8" class="decades-label">The 2000s</label>
    </li>
    <li class="decades-item">
      <input type="checkbox" class="decades-input" id="decadesInput9">
      <span class="decades-span"></span>
      <label for="decadesInput9" class="decades-label">The 2010s</label>
    </li>
    <li class="decades-item">
      <input type="checkbox" class="decades-input" id="decadesInput10">
      <span class="decades-span"></span>
      <label for="decadesInput10" class="decades-label">The 2020s</label>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Зачем Вам делать массив в массиве, если можно просто при отметке чекбокса "30-е" вывести все 9 лет в цикле?

Comment: Покажите ваши попытки. Лично мне не понятно как это должно выглядеть.

Comment: @De.Minov, закрепил попытки своего кода, чтобы Вы лучше понимали ситуацию.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вариант, который считает количество десятилетий от выбранных лет.
В данный момент конечный код равен текущему (2022) и устанавливается самостоятельно.

При выборе чекбокса, цикл проходит по всем выбранным и получая их `value`, который равен десятилетию (`value="1930"`, `value="1940"` и т.д), после этого год передаётся в функцию `GetYearsDecade()` (описание её работы в комментариях к коду), во втором параметре указана проверка, что если в выбранное десятилетие входит конечная дата, то `GetYearsDecade()` должен вернуть "обрезанный массив" до конечной даты.

```js
let start = 1930, // Стартовая дата
    end = new Date().getFullYear(), // Конечная дата
    decade = Math.floor((end - start) / 10), // получаем кол-во десятилетий (1930 - 2022 = 92 / 10 = 9.2 -> округлить = 9)
    output = document.querySelector('#years'); // Сюда будем выводить разметку

// Создаём разметку чекбоксов
for(let i = 0; i <= decade; i++) {
  let curDecade = start+(i * 10); // Стартовая дата + шаг * 10
  output.innerHTML += `
    <label for="y${curDecade}">${curDecade}</label>
    <input type="checkbox" id="y${curDecade}" value="${curDecade}"><br>`; // Выводим разметку
}

// Добавляем слушатель
output.addEventListener('change', function(e) { // Если происходят изменение..
  if(e.target.tagName === 'INPUT') { // Проверяем, изменился ли в данный момент `input`
    let checked = output.querySelectorAll('input[type="checkbox"]:checked'); // Получаем все "чекнутые" input'ы
    if(checked.length > 0) { // Если этих инпутов больше нуля
      let years = []; // Создаём массив в котором будем хранить года
      checked.forEach(function(e, $i) { // Проходим по всем "чекнутым" input'ам
        let val = Number(e.value); // Получаем их value и конвертируем тип в Numberic
        years.push(GetYearsDecade(val, (end - val) < 10 ? end : false));
      });
      console.info(years); // Выводим массив
    }
  }
});

// GetYearsDecade - вернёт года десятилетия указанной даты первым параметром. Если вторым параметром передать год, то вернёт даты до указанного года (если год входит в десятилетие)
// GetYearsDecade(2020) -> [2020, 2021, ..., 2029];
// GetYearsDecade(2024) -> [2020, 2021, ..., 2029];
// GetYearsDecade(2020, 2024) -> [2020, 2021, ..., 2024];
// GetYearsDecade(2020, 2020) -> [2020];
// GetYearsDecade(2020, 1999) -> [2020, 2021, ..., 2029];

function GetYearsDecade(year, stop = false) {
  year = Math.floor(year / 10) * 10;
  let years = [];
  for(let i = year; i < year + 10; i++) {
    years.push(i);
    if(stop !== false && i === stop) break;
  }  
  return years
}
```

```html
<div id="years"></div>
```

Comment: Вы гений! Спасибо большое за код)

Comment: Ну гений это слишком, не за что)

Answer (score 2):

```js
document.querySelectorAll('input').forEach(input => {
  input.addEventListener('change',function() {    
    if (this.checked) {
      let start_year = +this.id;
      let result = [start_year];
      for (let i=1; i<10; i++) { 
        result.push(start_year+i);
      }
      console.log(result);
    }
  })
})
```

```html
<label for='1930'>1930-е</label>
<input type="checkbox" id="1930">
<label for='1940'>1940-е</label>
<input type="checkbox" id="1940">
```

Comment: Спасибо большое!